# Creating a new Dataframe from loop on old dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a time series of prices(pt) that looks as follows:

```
head(MyData)
           A     B     C
2005-07-29 66.82 41.80 372.0
2005-08-01 68.94 42.70 373.0
2005-08-02 70.22 43.75 379.2
2005-08-03 70.79 43.75 385.6
2005-08-04 70.42 44.10 390.0
2005-08-05 69.84 43.60 386.0
```

Consideri ng a lookback window of say 3 days (w=3), I am trying to create a new dataframe with time series of the following:

x(ti) =  1/w (Pt/Pt + Pt-1/Pt + Pt-2/Pt)

I have used the following code:

```
nR<-nrow(MyData)
 nC<-ncol(MyData)
 x<-data.frame()
 for (j in 1:nC){
    for(i in 1:nR-w+1){

   x[i,j]<-rowSums(MyData[i:(w+i-1),j])

               }
}
```

however, i get the following error message:

```
Error in rval[i, j, drop = drop., ...] : 
only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

this seems to suggest something is wrong with my loop? or is it syntax? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Should it be `for(i in 1:(nR - w + 1))`?

Comment: did you notice that the result of `1:nR-w+1` gives negative results? This means that your subscripts are asking for e.g: x[-1,5] and i suppose that this is not an acceptable request

Comment: Grrrr!! thanks Josh & MaZe. The brackets seemed to have sorted out the problem but now i have an array error: Error in rowSums(MyData[i:(w + i - 1), j]) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Comment: `MyData[i:(w+i-1),j` has only 1 column as `j` is a single number. You won't be able to `sum` over a single value.

Comment: Thanks Akhil. I have now Managed to fix the issue. I also used sumRows insead of sumCols.

Comment: I solved the issue using the following Code:        nR<-nrow(MyData)
      x<-data.frame()      Xt<-data.frame()
 
         for(i in 1:(nR-w+1)) {
                 x<-colSums(MyData[i:(w+i-1),],na.rm=TRUE)
                 x<-x/(MyData[i+w-1,]*w)
                 Xt<-rbind(y,x)
                         }

names(Xt)<-colnames(MyData)